# is there a way to get workflow id while running gh action

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm generating workflow logs in this format while running GitHub action

```
${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}.log
```

I want to get the workflow id which we see in the rest call

```
"workflow_runs": [
    {
      "id": 30433642,
       "name": "Build",
    }
  ]
```

checked here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

is there a way we can get workflow id while running gh action?

Comment: Yes, you can get the **run_id** from the workflow **Github Context**. Here is an example of what it will return on the JSON format on a PR: https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d (and here a workflow implementation to show or manipulate the object: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/24-contexts.yml with a run example: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/3877788627?check_suite_focus=true). Let me know if it's enough to resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.

You can get the **run_id** from the workflow **Github Context**.

##### Example for the Github Context from a PR event:

```json
{
  "token": "***",
  "job": "github-context",
  "ref": "refs/pull/16/merge",
  "sha": "b4f1729888b5c99abdf8a7a250ecc6cff1e180be",
  "repository": "GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
  "repository_owner": "GuillaumeFalourd",
  "repositoryUrl": "git://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
  "run_id": "974568708",
  "run_number": "2",
  "retention_days": "90",
  "actor": "GuillaumeFalourd",
  "workflow": "24 - Github Context",
  "head_ref": "feature/readme",
  "base_ref": "main",
  "event_name": "pull_request",
  "event": {...}
}
```

- [Here is a workflow implementation showing how to manipulate this JSON object](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/24-contexts.yml).
- You can find [the associated run example here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/3877788627?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: you may refer to all jobs list, not to which was gced